# Test Method of class calls method of another class passed to it?

Tags: php, phpunit

To state the problem simply:

- Say I have two abstract classes, `Foo` and `Baz`.
- And say `Baz` defines a method, `biz()`, which expects an instance of `Foo`.

  `public function biz(Foo $foo): void {...}`

Is it possible to test that `Baz->biz()` calls a specific method of the `Foo` instance passed to it?

My hunch after much struggle is that it may not be possible to write such a test...

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
abstract class Foo ()
{

    abstract public function bar(): void;

    ...

}

abstract class Baz()
{

    public function biz(Foo $foo): void
    {
        $foo->bar();
    }

    abstract public function buz(): void;
    
    ...

}

final class BazTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testBazzerCallsFooInstancesBarMethod() {

        $mockFoo = $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)
            ->setMethods(['bar'])
            ->getMock();

        $mockBaz = $this->getMockBuilder(Baz::class)
            ->setMethods(['biz', 'buz'])
            ->getMock();

        /**
         * Problem: How do I test that $mockBaz->biz() calls $mockFoo->bar() internally,
         * or is this not possible? The following approach does not work...
         */
        $mockFoo->expects($this->once())
            ->method('bar');

        $mockBaz->biz($mockFoo);

    }

}
```

Comment: The real point is that you shouldn't. Your unit test should make sure your class works as expected. It should not be concerned with details of the implementation, it should only be concerned with getting the right output for certain parameters.

Comment: You comment also makes me wonder, should I try to avoid using PhpUnit idioms such as, $mockFoo->expects($this->once())->method('bar'), since that is testing an implementation detail, i.e. the calling of a specific method...? or am i am i misunderstanding the purpose of expects()?

Comment: Okay, so I think i understand, instead of testing the `Baz->biz()` calls `Foo->bar()`, i could instead test the the results of independently calling `Baz->biz()` match the results of independently calling`Foo->bar()`?

Comment: `public function testExample() : void { ... $this->assertEquals($bar->biz($foo), $foo->bar());  ... }`

Comment: ^ For example...?

Comment: If that's all that `biz()` does (just returns whatever `bar()` returns), then yes, you could just compare the results and see if they're the same. As for the mocks, I almost never use them. They're useful for unit testing things that, for example, store things in the database. Since unit test shouldn't interact with the db, you create a mock that simply tests if the method that does the db thing was invoked. But instead of doing that, I cover the important db interacting aspects with integration testing.